# Illustrator CC How do I draw within a layer group

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have created a layer and within it a group to which I have put a transform effect to do symmetry. While it works fine, I have to manually place each new object I create into the group. I have never understood if I have a group selected when I begin a new object, why it will not end up within the group. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Double click the grouped object to enter the group (in isolation mode), then add your new object. It will now be inside the group.

Double click outside the group to exit the group (to exit isolation mode).

For more info see https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html - scroll down to the section titled "Isolate a path, object, or group".  There are several methods listed, including the double click method.

Comment: It would be easier to put the effect on a layer or sublayer. Thatway you dont need to go out to isolation mode, just have layer active.

Comment: The effects in Illustrator only affect one objects or all objects in a group. If I ungroup it, the effect disappears.